# Plotly: How to change the colorscheme of a plotly express scatterplot?

Tags: python, plotly, data-visualization, visualization

I am trying to work with [`plotly`](https://plotly.com/), specifically [`ploty express`](https://plotly.com/python/plotly-express/), to build a few visualizations.

One of the things I am building is a [scatterplot](https://plotly.com/python/line-and-scatter/)

I have some code below, that produces a nice scatterplot:

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go, pandas as pd, plotly.express as px
df = pd.read_csv('iris.csv')
fig = px.scatter(df, x='sepal_length', y='sepal_width',
              color='species', marker_colorscale=px.colors.sequential.Viridis)
fig.show()
```

[image]

However, I want to try and change the colorscheme, i.e., the colors presented for each species.

I have read:

- https://plotly.com/python/builtin-colorscales/
- https://plotly.com/python/colorscales/
- https://plotly.com/python/v3/colorscales/

But can not get the colors to change.

Trying:

```
fig = px.scatter(df, x='sepal_length', y='sepal_width',
              color='species', marker_colorscale=px.colors.sequential.Viridis)
```

yields:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-78a9d58dce23> in <module>
      2 # https://plotly.com/python/line-and-scatter/
      3 fig = px.scatter(df, x='sepal_length', y='sepal_width',
----> 4               color='species', marker_colorscale=px.colors.sequential.Viridis)
      5 fig.show()

TypeError: scatter() got an unexpected keyword argument 'marker_colorscale'
```

Trying

Trying:

```
fig = px.scatter(df, x='sepal_length', y='sepal_width',
              color='species', continuous_colorscale=px.colors.sequential.Viridis)
```

yields:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-78a9d58dce23> in <module>
      2 # https://plotly.com/python/line-and-scatter/
      3 fig = px.scatter(df, x='sepal_length', y='sepal_width',
----> 4               color='species', continuous_colorscale=px.colors.sequential.Viridis)
      5 fig.show()

TypeError: scatter() got an unexpected keyword argument 'continuous_colorscale'
```

How can I change the colors used in a `plotly` visualization?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Generally, changing the color scheme for a plotly express figure is very straight-forward. What's causing the problems here is the fact that `species` is a **categorical variable**. Continuous or numerical values are actually easier, but we'll get to that in a bit.

For categorical values, using `color_discrete_map` is a perfectly valid, albeit cumbersome approach. I prefer using the keyword argument `continuous_colorscale` in combination with `px.colors.qualitative.Antique`, where `Antique` can be changed to any of the [discrete color schemes](https://plotly.com/python/discrete-color/#color-sequences-in-plotly-express) available in plotly express. Just run `dir(px.colors.qualitative)` to see what are available to you in the plotly version you are running:

```
['Alphabet',
 'Antique',
 'Bold',
 'D3',
 'Dark2',
 'Dark24',
 'G10',......]
```

**Code 1:**

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.iris()
fig = px.scatter(df, x="sepal_width", y="sepal_length",
                 color="species", color_discrete_sequence=px.colors.qualitative.Antique)

fig.show()
```

**Plot 1:**

[image]

***So what about continuous variables?***

Consider the following snippet:

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.iris()
fig = px.scatter(df, x="sepal_width", y="sepal_length",
                 color="sepal_length", color_continuous_scale=px.colors.sequential.Viridis)

fig.show()
```

Running this will produce this plot:

[image]

You can change the colors to any other theme available under `dir(px.colors.sequential)`, for example `color_continuous_scale=px.colors.sequential.Inferno`, and get this plot:

[image]

What's possibly causing confusion here, is that setting `color='species`, and keeping `color_continuous_scale=px.colors.sequential.Inferno` will give you this plot:

[image]

The figure now jumps straight back to using the default plotly colors, ***without*** giving you any warning about `color_continuous_scale=px.colors.sequential.Inferno` not having an effect.
This is because `species` is a categorical variable with these different values : `['setosa', 'versicolor', 'virginica']`, so `color_continuous_scale` is simply ignored. For `color_continuous_scale` to take effect you'll have to use a numerical value, like `sepal_length = [5.1, 4.9, 4.7, 4.6, 5. , 5.4, ...]`

And this brings us right back to my initial answer for categorical values:

> Use the keyword argument `continuous_colorscale` in combination with
>   `px.colors.qualitative`

Comment: What if you added two plots together using go.Figure, similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/65134290/13697228

Comment: What if you wanted to specify the `color_discrete_sequence` value in an update statement rather than directly in the chart instantiation api, how would you do that?

Comment: Sterling: I tested two scatter plots overlaying a stacked bar chart and set a different “color_discrete_sequence” for each fig (before combination) and it seems to be working fine. Is there a specific issue you are having?

Comment: Is it possible to change the defaults for all plots?

Answer (score 17):

You can use a method called `color_discrete_map`, which is a dict of `k,v` pairs where the `k` is the value for the color and `v` is the colorscheme. For example:

```
fig = px.scatter(df, x='sepal_length', y='sepal_width',
              color='species', color_discrete_map={'setosa': 'lightcyan', 
                                                   'versicolor': 'royalblue', 'virginica': 'darkblue'})
```

[image]