# get different colors for different categorical levels in a single line chart python Plotly

Tags: python, dataframe, plotly, linechart, plotly-python

Dataframe consists of 3 columns: Day-Shift, Brand, Production. Sometimes Brand changes(ex: A to B).
Need to plot a line chart using **Python Plotly**, setting x-axis as Day-Shift and Y as Production. **But when the Brand Changes, the New brand's line chart should be a new color.**

Ex: Night 10-01 to Night 10-04 Production with one color(for Brand A) and after that another color(for the brand B). color should change when the Brand Change.

```
Day-Shift   Brand   Production
Night 10-01 A       10
Day 10-01   A       21
Night 10-02 A       321
Day 10-02   A       2122
Night 10-03 A       0
Day 10-03   A       729
Night 10-04 A       200
Day 10-04   B       620
Night 10-05 B       75
Day 10-05   B       611
Night 10-06 B       0
Day 10-06   B       0
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for the [`color`](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.express.line.html) parameter?

See below:

```
import pandas as pd, plotly.express as px

# Copied from SO question
df = pd.read_clipboard()

fig = px.line(df, x='Day-Shift', y='Production', color='Brand')
fig.show()
```

yields:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. How do we give different fixed colors for each brand? For example Brand A : Green Brand B: Orange

Comment: @kevin no problem. I once asked a similar question (for scatterplots, but the logic is the same) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60962274/plotly-how-to-change-the-colorscheme-of-a-plotly-express-scatterplot